# sapply unintentionally merges values of a table

Tags: r, sapply

I am comparing results from different data.frames and I've put all of them into a list. I use sapply to see results for selected questions, however sometimes it shows different values as if they were the same, why?

This happens even in the simplest of cases such as:

> x = c(1, 2, **3**)
>
> y = c(1, 2, **4**)
>
> sapply(list(x,y), function(z) table(z))

[,1] [,2]

1    1    1

2    1    1

**3    1    1**

The 4 is shown as a 3, why?

Comment: The order matters. If you change the order to list(y, x) you will get 1, 2, 4.

Comment: `sapply` is dangerous when you have heterogeneous output as it will use heuristic function `simplify2array` to simplify output. From documentation: `sapply is a user-friendly version and wrapper of lapply by default returning a vector, matrix or, if simplify = "array", an array if appropriate, by applying simplify2array(). sapply(x, f, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE) is the same as lapply(x, f).`

Comment: You are right, simplifying is the problem, although without it I get separate lists, properly labelled though. I guess, I used a wrong tool for the task of comparing. Thank you :)  
       
> sapply(list(x,y), function(z) {table(z)}, simplify = FALSE)
[[1]]
z
1 2 3 
1 1 1 

[[2]]
z
1 2 4 
1 1 1